# Numpy Arrays in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have a list of numpy arrays and a list of labels that I would like to train a CNN with in keras.

What object do I need to convert the list of numpy arrays into?

Would it be a tensorflow tensor object (as in tf.convert_to_tensor) or something different?

I suppose I just would like to understand how I go from raw np arrays to something that can be tangibly trained on in keras.

Comment: `keras` should work with numpy arrays (to set the weights for example). What exactly do you want to do and why do you think it won't work?

Comment: @a_guest why does it not require a tensor object like tensorflow? do i feed the keras model a (m,n,r) numpt array for training on m, n x r arrays?

Comment: Because it will be converted internally. When you use `tensorflow` directly you also pass a `numpy` array to `feed_dict` for example.